# SQL query results are duplicating

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

Using below query

> SELECT *
>             FROM Customer, Orders, Orderline, Product

Results with 6500 rows as a result instead of 30 rows. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

```
Customer

----------------------------------------   
CustomerNo CustomerName CustomerAddress
----------------------------------------

1          Harry        19 mousemat

2          Potter       98a speakers

Orders
-------------------------------
OrderID CustomerNo OrderDate
-------------------------------

 1       1         12/3/1992

 2       2         13/5/1997



OrderLine
-----------------------------
OrderID ProductID ProductQty 
-----------------------------
1       100       27 

2       101       30


Products
-----------------------------------
ProductID ProductDesc ProductPrice
-----------------------------------

100       Blue        0.13 

101       Yellow      1.21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a JOIN statement between the tables. If there are still duplicates use the distinct keyword after the select keyword as well:

```
select distinct * 
from a
    join b on b.id = a.id
    join c on c.id = b.id
```

Here is what it would look like in your case:

```
select *
from Customer C
    join Orders O on (O.CustomerNo = C.CustomerNo)
    join OrderLine OL on (OL.OrderID = O.OrderID)
    join Products P on (P.ProductID = OL.ProductID);
```

The join statement is an inner/natural join by default. You want to link up the tables by what they have in common as a primary/secondary key.

When you don't have joins between multiple tables in sql, sql will make combinations between them. This is why you end up with 6500 rows instead of 30.

Answer (score 1):

You should use JOINS to link the tables on the right keys.

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orderline OL
JOIN Orders O
    ON OL.OrderId = O.OrderId
JOIN Product P
    ON OL.ProductId = P.ProductId
JOIN Customer C
    ON O.CustomerNo = C.CustomerNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the query is just `SELECT * FROM Customer, Orders, Orderline, Product` then you made an "implicit" `CROSS JOIN` or cartesian join in your query. When using multiple tables in your query you should specify `JOIN` - how you want to connect them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customer as c
INNER JOIN Orders as o
ON c.CustomerNo = o.CustomerNo
INNER JOIN Orderline as ol
ON o.OrderID = ol.OrderID 
INNER JOIN Product as p
ON ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: This worked thanks so much. I completely spaced joins and tried using indexes to begin with!!